# Import variable from bleg to aleg‏

Tags: freeswitch

I need to import a variable from b-leg to a-leg but renaming. I use the parameter

```
<action application="set" data="import=this_is_a_variable_name"/>
```

https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Variable_import

The problem is that I can not change the name of the variable.  Change the value of the variable in aleg.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: What you're trying to achieve with this. Do you want to send bleg var to aleg client directly or to update in aleg channel?

Comment: Send directly from bleg to aleg without  change value in aleg, create a new variable with this data.